# buildingjavaprograms Parameter Mystery

Tags: java

I am encountering difficulties with this one:

```
public class MisterySoda {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String soda = "coke";
    String pop = "pepsi";
    String coke = "pop";
    String pepsi = "soda";
    String say = pop;

    carbonated(soda, pop, pepsi);        // say pepsi not soda or coke
    carbonated(coke, soda, pop);         // 
    carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);       // 
    carbonated("pop", pop, "koolaid");   // 
    carbonated(say, "say", pop);         // 
}
public static void carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop) {
    System.out.println("say " + soda + " not " + pop + " or " + coke);
} }
```

When I compile I get the following output:

```
say pepsi not soda or coke
say coke not pepsi or pop
say soda not soda or pepsi
say pepsi not koolaid or pop
say say not pepsi or pepsi
```

Can someone explain how `carbonated()` uses the strings in question to deliver that output? Is there anyone who can clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are becoming confused because of your naming convention. It will make this a lot easier if you clear up your names:

```
public class MisterySoda {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String soda = "soda";
    String pop = "pop";
    String coke = "coke";
    String pepsi = "pepsi";
    String say = pop;

    carbonated(soda, pop, pepsi);        // say pepsi not soda or coke
    carbonated(coke, soda, pop);         // 
    carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);       // 
    carbonated("pop", pop, "koolaid");   // 
    carbonated(say, "say", pop);         // 
}
public static void carbonated(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
     System.out.println("say " + str1 + " not " + str2 + " or " + str3);
} }
```

Now the output will be more intuitive:

```
say soda not pop or pepsi
say coke not soda or pop
say pop not pepsi or pepsi
say pop not pop or koolaid
say pop not say or pop
```

The order in which the parameters are passed into `carbonated()` is what matters, not the variable names local to the function `carbonated()`.

Comment: But when you say String soda = "soda"; are you in fact creating a new String object "soda"?

Answer (score 0):

`soda` variable is actually `coke` in the `carbonated` method, see this illustration:

```
carbonated(      soda,          pop,      pepsi)
                   ↓             ↓           ↓
carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop)
```

- The **first** parameter `coke` will be printed in the *last* of the sentence
- The **second** parameter `soda` will be printed in the first of the sentence
- The **last** parameter `pop` will be concatenated in the middle

Remember, it's the *order* that's important, not the *variables names*.

Comment: Thanks Mr Maroun, but I just don't get it. The System.out.println("say " + soda + " not " + pop + " or " + coke);

Answer (score 0):

The variable names are confusing. Compare with the below program where the names are "neutral". Should make sense now.

```
public class MisterySoda {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "coke";
    String b = "pepsi";
    String c = "pop";
    String d = "soda";
    String e = b;

    carbonated(a, b, d);
    carbonated(c, a, b);
    carbonated(b, d, d);
    carbonated("pop", b, "koolaid");
    carbonated(e, "say", b);
}
public static void carbonated(String x, String y, String z) {
    System.out.println("say " + y + " not " + z + " or " + x);
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
public static void carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop) {
System.out.println("say " + soda + " not " + pop + " or " + coke);
}
```

in its simplist form is

```
public static void function(String string1, String string2, String string3){
System.out.println("say " + string2 + " not " + string3 + " or " + string1);}
```

so when you call the function you are really writing your pre-defined strings to string1, string2 and string3.

Good practice would say to use helpful variables in your function to avoid confusion when calling your function.